# removeFromSuperview() blocks UIView Input

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Firstly, no this is not a dupe I have tried many of the answers on here to similar questions to no avail.

When I press the hideButton and run the removeFromSuperview() theOneView is removed, when I press the menuButton, theOneView is recreated but does not accept input? Can anyone help please?

theOneView is a view on my viewcontroller.

```
  import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var MyView: UIView!

    @IBAction func showButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print ("Show")
        if (MyView != nil){
            MyView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: MyView.frame)
        let inputURL = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: inputURL!))
        MyView.addSubview(webView)
        self.view.addSubview(MyView)
        //theOneView.bringSubview(toFront: webView)
        //self.view.bringSubview(toFront: theOneView)
    }

    @IBAction func hideButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print ("Hide")
        MyView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of commented code. Please remove any needless code from your question and only post code relevant to your issue.

Comment: Uploaded cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:

> func removeFromSuperview()
>
> Unlinks the view from its superview and its window, and removes it
>   from the responder chain. If the view’s superview is not nil, the
>   superview releases the view. Calling this method removes any
>   constraints that refer to the view you are removing, or that refer to
>   any view in the subtree of the view you are removing.

Instead you should use view's `hidden` property.

Comment: The problem is I am trying to reload the MyView subview so on button presses I can recreate a MyView with a different URL. The only easy way I have found to do this is to destroy and remake the subview. Is there any way to link the view correctly after the removeFromSuperView?

Comment: I don't think you should use a subview to display a webview. Try to change your code like [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview). Then you only need to reload the webview with a new url.

Comment: Have tried and it does not work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592297/how-to-change-urls-using-only-one-wkwebview